# Json ответ в "неправильной кодировке" отображает русские символы

Tags: кодировка, json, php

Добрый день.

Json ответ в "неправильной кодировке" отображает русские символы. Если символы английские, то всё ок, а если кириллица, то такой вот вид:

```
[{"Id":"1","Fio":"Rakzin Roman"},{"Id":"2","Fio":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447"},{"Id":"3","Fio":"\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432 \u041f\u0451\u0442\u0440 \u041f\u0435\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447"},........
```

Php:

```
echo json_encode($this->Vipolnit_Zapros("Select Id,Fio from Students"));
```

Подскажите, что делать. Как убрать такие вот символы: `\u0418`? Хотя потом в JavaScript всё хорошо отображается, но хотелось бы это убрать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Как убрать такие вот символы: \u0418?
> Хотя потом в JavaScript всё хорошо
> отображается, но хотелось бы это
> убрать.

Чтобы их убрать, используйте второй параметр функции [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php):

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`**  - Не кодировать многобайтные символы Unicode (по умолчанию они кодируются как \uXXXX). [Доступно начиная с PHP 5.4.0.](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php)

Answer (score 12):

Всё нормально, `"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447"` - это не "кодировка", а "коды символов юникода", записанные в восьмибитной кодировке, точнее записан текст `"Иванов Иван Иванович"`.

В json данные записываются в ASCII 0-127. Всё, что не влезает, записывается как коды юникода (`"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432"` это `"Иванов"`).

Comment: это не "восьмибитная кодировка", а обычные шестнадцатиричные числа, например, `447` это `1095` в десятичной системе, что соответствует `"ч"` символу в Юникоде. Не обязательное кодировать json-текст, используя ascii, например, можно использовать utf-8, utf-16be.

Comment: @jfs 

 1. как раз восьмибитная кодировка ASCII
    0-127, (не путайте "кодировку" и
    "таблицу символов и кодов")
 2. а вот это, из разряда вредные
    советы:
    > Не обязательно кодировать json-текст,
    > используя ascii, например, можно
    > использовать utf-8, utf-16be.
    
    в этом случае вы можете получить
    проблемы с кодировкой символов,
    именно из за этой проблемы в JSON де
    факто используется `ASCII 0-127`.
    Разумеется если грамотно всё и везде
    настроить то проблемы не будет, но
    куда проще использовать "коды
    символов юникода"

Comment: полный бред. Формат json определён для Юникодного текста.  Например:`"\u0418"` -- json строка, которая может быть закодирована в байты, используя разные кодировки. Чаще всего это utf-8, но в зависимости от приложения другие кодировки могут быть более предпочтительны. Использование только символов, представимых в ascii кодировке -- плохая метод исправления приложения, которое не корректно с кодировками работает.

Comment: тихо положу [спеку](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: [Здесь](http://json.org/) та же информация, только изложено в 10 раз короче.

Answer (score 9):

Любой символ в json-строке может быть представлен в виде последовательности `\uxxxx` даже английские символы, например, `"V"` соответствует `"\u0056"`. Не BMP символы (вне `U+0000-U+FFFF`) могут быть представлены в виде суррогатной пары UTF-16 (такой как `"\ud83c\udf82"` -- соответствует символу [U+1F382 BIRTHDAY CAKE](http://codepoints.net/U+1F382)). Шестнадцатеричные цифры `xxxx` кодируют номер символа (Unicode codepoint).

[JSON формат](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) определён для Юникодного текста. При записи в файл, передачи по сети или другому байтовому интерфейсу может потребоваться закодировать этот текст как последовательность байтов, используя utf-8, utf-16, или utf-32 кодировки (кодировки рекомендованные [rfc 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)).

`\uxxxx` последовательности позволяют сохранить json-текст, используя ascii кодировку. Чтобы оставить символы как есть, `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` можно использовать как [@mantigatos предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/377669#378919).

[`"V"` и `"\u0056"` json строки декодируются `json_decode()` в один и тот же символ](http://ideone.com/lMHSIT).