# Сохранение специальных символов (non-ASCII) в JSON

Tags: python, json

Как сохранять специальные символы (°, $, ¥, степени числа) в JSON?

При парсинге данных (с помощью python, scrapy) попадается много специфических символов, которые не отображаются в человекоподобном виде.

Например, значение температуры - 1021 °C, на выходе получаю

```
>>> response.xpath('path').extract()
u'1021 \xb0C'
>>> print(response.xpath('path').extract())
1021 °C
```

И при формировании JSON-объекта получаю

```
 [{
 ..."temp": "1021 \u00b0C", ...
 }]
```

А нужно

```
[{
 ..."temp": "1021 °C", ...
 }]
```

Как мне добиться человекоподобного вида в JSON? Чтобы символы оторажались как есть.

Comment: стандартом json такие символы запрещены, они обязаны быть закодированы. Вы конечно можете сами пройтись по json-тексту и преобразовать `\u` но потом такой json не факт что проглотят функции которые с ним должны работать

Comment: то есть оставить как есть в машинном виде? а если я буду импортировать данные в БД?

Comment: Если вы любой стандартной функцией этот json преобразуете в массив и будете его грузить, то в массиве то у вас все уже будет декодировано. А если сам json сохранять в БД то какая разница как он там выглядит

Comment: знак градуса сохранится в БД как \u00b0C или °C?

Comment: а вы что в БД сохранять то будете ? как json преобразуете в формат БД ?

Comment: немного не понял вопрос. сохранять буду значения и размерности величин, в конкреттном случае 1021 и знак градуса, json намереваюсь использовать как промежуточный формат для хранения данных между парсингом и импортом из него в БД

Comment: Вы парсить json перед загрузкой в БД чем будете ? какую нибудь библиотечную функцию ведь возьмете ? Так вот любые функции при декодировнии json разумеется превратят `\u` в сами символы

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Про импорт в БД еще не думал конкретно, работаю над парсингом и появился озвученный вопрос.

Comment: @Mike не вводите человека в заблуждение. json конечно же поддерживает эти символы. json это текстовый формат, который определён в терминах Юникода. Экранированные последовательности такие как `\uxxxx` позволяют произвольный json текст передавать, используя ASCII кодировку, но конечно же, не обязательно эти последовательности использовать (кроме отдельных исключений). [близко к теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/378941/23044).

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете стандартную библиотеку `json` и не хотите видеть закодированные символы в результате преобразования, можно использовать дополнительный параметр `ensure_ascii` функции `dumps` (имеется также у функции `dump`):

```
>>> print(json.dumps('1021 °C', ensure_ascii=False))
"1021 °C"
```

---

Насколько я понимаю, JSON разрешает использовать произвольные Unicode символы в строках. Вот, что я нашёл в [спецификации](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt):

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the
>      quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped:
>      quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
>      through U+001F).

Что после вольного перевода читается как

> Внутри кавычек (") могут быть помещены любые юникодные символы, за исключением символов, которые обязательно должны быть экранированы: кавычки ("), обратная косая черта (\) и контрольные символы (с U+0000 до U+001F)

Тем не менее, перед использованием подобного режима записи JSON, проверьте, что библиотека, используемая для парсинга JSON работает с юникодными символами.