# Python. Как декодировать json, содержащий кириллицу?

Tags: python, json

Работаю с данными из твиттера, все твиты сохраняются в json файл.
В файле встречаются(вместо кириллицы) такие символы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как декодировать уже записанный файл?

Вот код, который использовался для сбора данных:

```
def save_track_keywords():
"""
Track two keywords with a tracking stream and save machting tweets.
To stop the stream, press ctrl-c or kill the python process.
"""
# Set up file to write to
outfile = open("keywords_example.json", "w")

   def save_tweet(tweet):
       json.dump(tweet, outfile)
       # Insert a newline after one tweet
       outfile.write("\n")
   keywords = ["коррупция"]
   try:
       stream = streaming.stream(
           on_tweet=save_tweet, on_notification=print_notice, track=keywords)
   except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
       logging.error("User stopped program, exiting!")
       outfile.flush()
       outfile.close()
```

Есть еще такая функция, которая сохранит данные в базу данных в нужной мне кодировке:

```
  def import_json(fi):
     """
     Load json data from a file into the database.
     """
     logging.warning("Loading tweets from json file {0}".format(fi))
     for line in open(fi, "rb"):
        data = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
        database.create_tweet_from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Пример кода в студию! А `encoding='utf-8'` пробовали использовать? По умолчанию, используется системная кодировка, а на винде это скорее всего будет cp1251

Comment: @gil9red Добавила код в описание.

Comment: Давайте уточним, проблема возникает в `import_json`, в `data = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))`? У вас исключение возникает? Или проблема в том, что юникодные последовательсти вида `\u0423` не декодируются в нормальный вид?

Answer (score 1):

При записи достаточно передать `ensure_ascii=False`, чтобы не экранировать не-ascii символы:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps('ъ'))
"\u044a"
>>> print(json.dumps('ъ', ensure_ascii=False))
"ъ"
```

Обе json строки кодируют одну и ту же Питон строку.

Связанные вопросы:

- [Json ответ в "неправильной кодировке" отображает русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/378941/23044)
- [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)