# Python кодировки: в json файле кириллица выглядит так: \u043d\u0443\u044e \u043a\u0432

Tags: python, json, кодировка, utf-8

Добрый день.

Сохраняю в файл массив в формат json. Кодировку указываю `utf-8`.
Код выглядит так:

```
with open('mylist.json',"w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(out, file)
```

В файле кириллица выглядит так: `\u043d\u0443\u044e \u043a\u0432\`

Понимаю, что где-то с кодировками не порядок, но не пойму где. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так:

```
with open('mylist.json',"w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(out, file, ensure_ascii=False)
    #                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Тест:

```
In [97]: d = {'test':'фывапролджэ'}

In [98]: with open('c:/temp/mylist1.json',"w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    ...:     json.dump(d, file)
    ...:

In [99]: with open('c:/temp/mylist2.json',"w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    ...:     json.dump(d, file, ensure_ascii=False)
    ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [105]: open('c:/temp/mylist1.json', encoding='utf-8').read()
Out[105]: '{"test": "\\u0444\\u044b\\u0432\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u043e\\u043b\\u0434\\u0436\\u044d"}'

In [106]: open('c:/temp/mylist2.json', encoding='utf-8').read()
Out[106]: '{"test": "фывапролджэ"}'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Заработало!!! Не могу отметить полезность ответа - не хватает репутации  :-(

Comment: @StepanKurakin: стоит заметить, что с точки зрения json формата: `"\u0444"` и `"ф"` это одна и та же буква: [`json.loads(r'"\u0444"') == json.loads('"ф"')`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/378941/23044)