# Как записывать русские буквы в json файл на php?

Tags: php

При вызове функции `file_put_contents()` в файле появляются кракозябры вида `\u041a\u0438\u0440\` на месте русских букв. Насколько понял, дело в кодировке. Как сделать так, чтобы php корректно записывал буквы?

Comment: Он корректно записывает буквы. `json_decode()` всё вернёт на свои места. И это не кракозябры `\u` - юникод, `0438` - код символа

Comment: @ArchDemon, а нет ли способа эти буквы записывать также корректно, но на кириллице?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Json ответ в "неправильной кодировке" отображает русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/377669/json-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @ArchDemon - это символы в формате unicode. При декодировании все станет на свои места.

Но, если Вам очень хочется записывать юникод-символы as is:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Более подробно об константах для ф-и `json_encode` можете почитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php)