# Как сделать экранирование символов внутри значения JSON объекта

Tags: java, json, экранирование, escape

В общем есть нереляционная БД, в которую записываются JSON объекты. Обычно это массив. Проблема, с которой я борюсь, это кириллица, которая записывается по-волшебному (\uxxx). [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/377669/json-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) говорят, что это нормально.

Но я так не считаю, ибо смотреть эту шляпу, заглядывая в базу, не комильфо. С латиницей в это же время все ок.

Сейчас работает все так. Есть компонент на форме(JSF), в который вставляется значение JSON как String

Выглядит это так:

```
function updateComponentWithJSONArray(nameOfComponent2Update, JSONArray2Update) 
{
    getComponent(nameOfComponent2Update).setValue(new ru.generate.doc.JSONCyrillic.makeCyrillicGreatAgain(toJson(JSONArray2Update)));
    // Метод toJson возвращает String из JSONObject
}
```

Я решил эту проблему вызовом следующего кода. [String utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
public static String makeCyrillicGreatAgain(String jsonAsString) 
{
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(jsonAsString);
}
```

И все вроде бы работало, но потом я забавы ради решил двойные кавычки добавить. Ну и все накрылось после этого. Теперь простейший JSON объект типа {"companyName":"ООО "Рога и копыта""} именно так и анэскейпится, вместо того, чтобы `\"` перед кавычками добавлять. Очень печалит это. В то же время можно вообще не вызывать этот unescape и оставить все так:

```
function updateComponentWithJSONArray(nameOfComponent2Update, JSONArray2Update) 
{
    getComponent(nameOfComponent2Update).setValue(toJson(JSONArray2Update));
    // Метод toJson возвращает String из JSONObject
}
```

Но тогда заказчику вместо того, чтобы писать ООО "Рога и копыта", придется учить англ, чтобы вместо этого написать "Horns and hooves" LTD, или, того хуже, OOO "Roga i Kopyta". Кавычки нужны и обязательны.

Собственно, вопрос:

Возможно ли каким-нибудь образом сделать unescape, чтобы каждое значение (именно значение, за ключи я уверен) JSON объекта, заменили все `"` внутри значения на `\"`? Но это ведь дороха получается... Рекурсивно пройтись по всем JSON объектам, проверить каждое значение... Может, как-то по-другому можно эту проблему решить?

Comment: В принципе можно сделать через replace. Как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898773/java-escape-json-string Но правильнее было бы заглянуть в библиотеку, которую вы используете для сериализации.

Answer (score 0):

Ну что ж сказать, проблему я решил рекурсивно пробегаясь по каждому листочку JSON дерева, заменяя значения стандартной функцией replace от String. 
Выглядит это все вот так:

```
public static void iterateThroughEachLeafAndReplaceQuotes(Object input)
    {
        if(input instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            Iterator<String> keys = ((JSONObject) input).keys();
            while (keys.hasNext())
            {
                String key = keys.next();
                Object object =  ((JSONObject) input).get(key);

                if(object instanceof JSONObject
                        || object instanceof JSONArray)
                {
                    iterateThroughEachLeafAndReplaceQuotes(object);
                }
                else ((JSONObject) input).put(key, object // простой объект, аххаах, наканецта
                        .toString()
                        .replace("\\", "\\\\")
                        .replace("\"", "\\\"")); 

            }
        }
        else if(input instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            Iterator<Object> objectsInsideArray = ((JSONArray) input).iterator();
            while (objectsInsideArray.hasNext())
            {
                iterateThroughEachLeafAndReplaceQuotes(objectsInsideArray.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод, который отдает String и сетит компонент теперь выглядит так:

```
public static String makeCyrillicGreatAgain(String jsonAsString) 
{

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonAsString);
        iterateThroughEachLeafAndReplaceQuotes(array);
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(array.toString());
}
```

После этих манипуляций кириллица нормально отображается, а всякие `"` и `\` превращаются в `\"` и `\\` соответственно. Из `ООО "Рога и Копыта"` теперь получается `ООО \"Рога и копыта\"`