# Laravel вывод JSON ответа

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

уже всю голову сломал, почему выводит вместо нормального вывода вот такие кракозябры, причем на новой странице
{"successful":"\u0421\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e, \u0437\u0430 \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435! 
 \u041c\u044b \u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0438\u043c \u0412\u0430\u043c \u0441\u043e\u0432\u0441\u0435\u043c \u0441\u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e.</div>"}

Мой контроллер

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use App\Http\Requests\CalcMailRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\CalcMailRequest;
use App\Mail\MailSend;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailSetting extends Controller
{

    public function sendForm(Request $request, CalcMailRequest $mailRequest)
    //public function send(Request $request, CalcMailRequest $mailRequest)
    {
        $mailData = $request->all();
        // $mail = ['yshliu_lose@inbox.ru'];
        $mail = ['eliseev@gmail.com'];
        Mail::to($mail)->send(new MailSend($mailData));
        return response()->json([
        'successful'=>"<div class='message'>Спасибо, за обращение! <br> Мы ответим Вам совсем скоро.</div>"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Мой реквест файл

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CalcMailRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                return [
                    'height' => 'required',
                    'length' => 'required',
                    'userphone' => 'required',
                    'username' => 'required',
                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'height.required' => '* Укажите желаемую высоту забора!',
            'length.required' => '* Укажите желаемую длинну забора!',
            'userphone.required' => '* Вы не указали телефон!',
            'username.required' => '* Укажите Ваше имя!',
        ];
    }
}
```

Моя форма со скриптом отправки AJAX запроса

```
<noindex>
<div id="new_form">
    <div class="some-form main-form"> 
    <h3>Моя форма</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('mail.send-mail')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="my-form uk-form js-form-validate" name="contact_form">
        @csrf

                    <div class="uk-margin some-form__line" style="display:flex">
                        <div class="some-form__line" style="width: 49%; margin-right: 1%;">
                            <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Высота забора, м*" name="height" type="text" id="height" data-validate>
                            <span class="some-form__hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="some-form__line" style="width: 49%; margin-left: 1%;">
                            <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Длина забора, м*" name="length" type="text" id="length" data-validate>
                            <span class="some-form__hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin some-form__line" style="display:flex">
                        <input class="uk-input" style="width: 49%; margin-right: 1%;" placeholder="Количество калиток, шт" name="numberofwicket" id="numberofwicket" type="text">             
                        <input class="uk-input" style="width: 49%; margin-left: 1%;" placeholder="Количество ворот, шт" name="numberofgates" id="numberofgates" type="text">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Удалённость от МКАД, км" name="distance" type="text" id="distance">   
                    </div>

                    <div class="uk-margin some-form__line" style="display:flex">
                        <div class="some-form__line" style="width: 49%; margin-right: 1%;">
                            <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Имя *" name="username" type="text" id="username" data-validate>
                            <span class="some-form__hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="some-form__line" style="width: 49%; margin-left: 1%;">
                            <input class="uk-input phone_number" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__ *" name="userphone" type="text" id="userphone" data-validate>
                            <span class="some-form__hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="e-mail" name="useremail" type="text">    
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                        <div class="uk-width-small@s">
                            <input class="btn" value="Отправить" type="submit" id="btn_submit" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand@s mini_text">
                            Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку своих персональных данных
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ URL::current() }}">
                    <div class='message'></div>
                </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</noindex>



<script type="text/javascript">

$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submit
    var url = '{{route('mail.send-mail')}}';
    // create the FormData object from the form context (this),
    // that will be present, since it is a form event
    var formData = new FormData(this); 
    // build the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('.my-form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            // handle success response
            console.log(response.successful);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            // handle error response
            console.log('Не работает');
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
})
```

Comment: Вообще должно быть, что внизу формы или вместо формы выводиться сообщение об удачной отправке

Comment: С кодировочкой проблемы... это "Спасибо, за обращение!\nМы ответим Вам совсем скоро."

Answer (score 2):

`"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447"` - это не "кодировка", а "коды символов юникода", записанные в восьмибитной кодировке, точнее записан текст "Иванов Иван Иванович".

В json данные записываются в ASCII 0-127. Всё, что не влезает, записывается как коды юникода (`"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432" это "Иванов"`).

Чтобы их убрать, используйте второй параметр функции json_encode():

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - Не кодировать многобайтные символы Unicode (по умолчанию они кодируются как \uXXXX). Доступно начиная с PHP 5.4.0.

Из ранее заданного [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/377669/json-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

JSON ответ является URI закодированным.

Вообще jQuery автоматически парсит json ответ (по крайней мере 3я версия). Можно в параметрах ajax запроса указать

```js
$.ajax('/ajax-url', {
  // ...
  dataType: 'json', // если этот параметр не указан, то jquery пытается сам определить тип ответа 
}).done(function(res){
  if(typeof res === 'string'){
    res = JSON.parse(res);
  }
  console.log(res);
  $('form').append(res.successful); // добавили в форму ответ
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы, в принципе все было верно как описали комментаторы выше, но дело оказалось в другом. До меня был написан на чистом JS код с валидацией и отправкой данных и этот код был жестко привязан только к одной форме, следовательно AJAX отправка формы в  не происходила и лара не видела JSON просто, писал на JQuery AJAX отправку, но она почему то конфликтовала с JS кодом выше. В итоге в ранее написанном JS коде привязал AJAX к разным формам и все заработало, думаю если бы я писал на JQuery изначально, было бы все проще.